# Linux: How to diagnose laptop battery issues?

Tags: thinkpad, battery

I use arch + wayland + sway on Lenovo thinkpad x390.

Recently my battery power indicator in bar sometimes shows these messages:

- `No battery` (happened only once)
- `-nan%`
- `inf%` (most common)
- or is stuck on very low percentage ex: `1.81%`

How can I diagnose this issue ? What software tools are good for checking my battery properties and health ?

Thank you for help

Comment: The diagnostic is old age.

Comment: But laptop it self is able to charge and run for ~4 hours. I fear it will be some mechanical damage. but first I would like to check if it is not software issue.